# Reference to non-existent subpattern

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I've made some progress with my regex that I'm using to extract attributes from pseudo-xml-tags, but then I got ambitous and wanted to correctly handle quoted attributes (with quotes being optional):

**regex**

```
~\{language\s*=\s*(P?<quote>[\"\']*)(?P<att>.*?)(?P=quote)\s*/\}~
```

(this is the output of the var that is used as arg in preg_match, so 'sensible things' such as \" were created with `chr(92) . chr(34)` beforehand...)

**input**

```
kjkjkjkjkjkj{language= 'DE' /}xxxxlxlxlxlllllk
```

extracts `'DE`' when testing with RegexBuddy. But PHPs preg_match issues a warning: Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: reference to non-existent subpattern at offset 56.

What's the problem? I thought "quote" was assigned before...

Here's the **complete program**, just in case I have a PHP-error somewhere:

```
<?php


$QQ=chr(92) . chr(34);
$delimeters = "{}";
$del0 = preg_quote($delimeters{0});
$del1 = preg_quote($delimeters{1});
$tag="language";

$string="fdfdfdfdf{language=1}testhgg";

$preg1 = "|" . $del0 . $tag . "[^" . $del1 . "]*" . $del1 . "(.*?)" . $del0 . "/" . $tag . $del1 . "|";
$preg2 = "~" . $del0 . $tag . "\s*=\s*(?P<" . "quote>[" . $QQ . "\']*)(?P<att>.*?)(?P=quote)\s*/" . $del1 . "~";

$match=array();
preg_match($preg1,$string,$match);
echo "<br>match1:<pre>";var_dump($match);echo"</pre>";

$match=array();
preg_match($preg2,$string,$match);
echo "<br>match2:<pre>";var_dump($match);echo"</pre>";

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your named subpattern is formatted incorrectly.

```
(P?<quote>[\"\']*)
```

should be

```
(?P<quote>[\"\']*)
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php

Comment: Thanks for that - fixed it...but I still do not get these matches into "$match" after preg_match($pattern,$string,$matches)...?

Comment: Thanks Cybogx37, you spotted the original issue! I'm know struggling with named captures not being returned, but this seems to be a PHP-Issue, as other PCRE-Implementations did so. I'll upgrade my PHP and will report this as a bug if it still exists...